# Add background color to text, but not to part where there is no text

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I want to display text on an image, but for low cell phone resolutions, the text cannot be read well...therefore, I want to add a black background to it, but to text only.

Setting colors for backgrounds and texts is easy, but it does not yield the result I need:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_bg

The div uses the color for the entire width of the div...
The "this is a heading" part has a black background for the entire part...

However, only the background of the letters should have a certain color.

e.g. "This is a textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

The background color should only be the background of "This is a text", but the remaining part of the width marked x should not have a background color.

How can I do this? I could use width=..., but the text width varies...basically, I only want to add a black background to all letters on top of an image...without adding the background color to a certain part of the image although there is no text displayed there.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `display: table`? the elements will not block the layout when this is set.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: blue;
}

h1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: table;
}

div {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This page has a grey background color and a blue text.</p>
<div>This is a div.</div>
```

Though I would recommend the best practice, which is to highlight the background color by wrapping the text in an additional element:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: blue;
}

h1 span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: table;
}

div span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is a Heading</span></h1>
<p>This page has a grey background color and a blue text.</p>
<div><span>This is a div.</span></div>
```